# how do i automatically check and link to those uploaded files on my webpage in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a script that pushes up files via ssh to certain webserver folders on my website.  I was wondering **how do i automatically check and link to those uploaded files on my webpage in wordpress?**  So i dont have to do this manually daily.

i know how to to do this in html but im lost already with wordpress. I would do it in html but i want to keep my theme and settings etc.

I have tried some googling around but with no luck.

If you could help me out or point me in the right direction id be very much appreciated :)

Im guessing i have to do a bit of php learning? 
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a WordPress shortcode or widget which you can place on your content page. Assuming you are new with php, I recommend go with a shortcode its easier to create. Here is a small shortcode I created for you. You may use it as it is but I recommend you create a sub directory in your main uploads directory and then modify the following code to point your new independent directory. Let me know if you need help with that too. Here is the code.

```
add_shortcode( 'list_uploads_dir', 'wpse39339084_list_uploads_dir' );
function wpse39339084_list_uploads_dir($args) {

    // Getting default uploads directory
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

    // Initiate the file system on front end
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');

    if ( ! WP_Filesystem() ) {
        request_filesystem_credentials($url, '', true, false, null);
        return;
    }

    // Get the list of files in uploads directory

    global $wp_filesystem;
    $filelist = $wp_filesystem->dirlist( $upload_dir['basedir'] );

    if ( $filelist ){
            foreach( $filelist as $file ) {
                echo '<a href="' . $upload_dir['baseurl'] . '/' . $file['name'] . '">' . $file['name'] . '</a><br/>';
            }

        }

}
```

Comment: wow thankyou heaps. That looks great and similar to C#. I will have a play around with it this weekend :) thank you again